# Why I obtain this FK error when I try to create this table? errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, rdbms

I have this **USER** table on a MySql DB:

```
id          bigint(20) unsigned     NO      PRI     NULL    auto_increment
username    varchar(30)             NO      NULL    
pswd        varchar(40)             NO      NULL
```

Then I am trying to create a new **ACCOMODATION** table having a **user_Id** field that is the foreign key of the previous **USER** table, I am doing in this way:

```
CREATE
    TABLE testdb.ACCOMODATION
    (
        Id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        user_Id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
        
        
        name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        tel VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        mobile VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        fax VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
        cap VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        nation VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        region VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        province VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        municipality VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        stars ENUM('ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR', 'FIVE') NOT NULL,
        lat BIGINT NOT NULL,
        lon BIGINT NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT fk_accomodation_user FOREIGN KEY (user_Id) REFERENCES testdb.user (Id),
        PRIMARY KEY (Id)
    )
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

But I obtain the following error message:

> #1005 - Can't create table `testdb`.`accomodation` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Your datatypes have to be exactly the same. `user_Id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL` has to be `user_Id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL` to match the reference.

Comment: that is no segment of a create table for user. Plus the error would be a 1215 @Solarflare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data type of user_id column in ACCOMODATION table must be exactly the same data type of id column in user table.

> user_id          bigint(20) unsigned     NO     NULL

Answer (score 1):

These definitions are not the same:

```
id          bigint(20) unsigned     NO      PRI     NULL    auto_increment

user_Id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL
```

An unsigned `bigint` is not the same as a signed `bigint`.  The columns used in a foreign key reference need to have exactly the same types as the columns in the original table.